# Duplication of package scala.sys.process in SBT

Tags: sbt

For managing and starting processes, in Scala we have the package `scala.sys.process`.

But SBT have nearly all the classes in that package replicated in the `sbt` package, with slight variations.

E.g. we have [scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder) and [sbt.ProcessBuilder](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/index.html#sbt.ProcessBuilder).

I wonder:

- Why this duplication?
- Which one should be used?.

I've decided to use the standard Scala package, but don't know if this the best decision.  I've checked that it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got imported into `scala-library` as of 2.9.0, see [5bada81](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/5bada810b4c7eda186aa40b94a78326520b3fa92).

I've not seen anyone recommend using Scala's Process API over sbt, so I've continued to use sbt's.

Also in one case with both `sbt._` and `scala.sys.process._` imports present I've seen IntelliJ throw some false positive errors.

Comment: OK, I understand, it's for historical reasons.  The 1st implementation was in SBT, and was ported later to Scala, with few modifications.

Comment: Yeah probably a few on initial import and a few over time. And SBT hasn't removed it as it's maintaining backwards compatibility.

Comment: It seems it has been removed in [sbt/util@4629053](https://github.com/sbt/util/commit/4629053277afb703829ca2b586d4b4ed12e35e17)